# Call template specialization with more parameters for specific value of one-parameter template call

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I have a template that takes 2 parameters. For a certain value of the first parameter, I know what the second parameter should be.  I would like to have only one full definition of my template (the one that takes 2 arguments), and be able to instantiate my template supplying only one argument.

In the following example, I know that if the first template parameter is `Foo1`, the second should be `Foo2`.  I'd like to be able to create a `Someclass<Foo1,Foo2>` by writing `Someclass<Foo1>`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Foo1 { Foo1() { cout << "Foo1 "; }};
struct Foo2 { Foo2() { cout << "Foo2 "; }};

template <typename ...Dummy> struct SomeClass;
template <typename T, typename U> struct SomeClass<T,U> {
  SomeClass() {
    T t;
    U u;
  }
};

/* Here, some one-argument specialization where if SomeClass<Foo1> is desired,
 * SomeClass<Foo1, Foo2> is obtained. */

int main() {
  SomeClass<Foo1, Foo2> c; //prints "Foo1 Foo2 "
  SomeClass<Foo1> c2;      //Should print the same thing, right now "incomplete type"
}
```

I guess I'm going to have to make a specialization that takes 2 arguments, the first being `Foo1`, like so:

```cpp
template <typename U> struct SomeClass<Foo1, U> {
  SomeClass() {
    Foo1 f;
    U u;
  }
};
```

But how do I make a specialization that accepts only one parameter `Foo1` and results in a `SomeClass<Foo1,Foo2>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution for the case of a class template would probably be to define a specialization that matches the case you're interested in and have that "forward" to the specialization with the arguments you want that to map to by inheriting from it:

```cpp
template <typename ...Dummy>
struct SomeClass
{
    // default implementation
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct SomeClass<T, U>
{
    // case for two parameters
};

template <> struct SomeClass<Foo1> : public SomeClass<Foo1, Foo2> {};
```

Comment: You cannot specialize alias templates. The alternative doesn't work. https://godbolt.org/z/SfabM6

Comment: Thank you!  The first solution works well.  I didn't think to use inheritance for this.

I would have loved for the second one to work, but I'm getting an  `error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'`

Comment: @MaxLanghof I don't know what hit me. I swear I tried this on godbolt before posting and it looked like it compiled…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel godbolt has been a bit wonky for me today so maybe that's what got you...

Comment: @MaxLanghof I was even surprised that it would work since I remember being annoyed to hell and back by not being able to partially specialize alias templates. But it's just a full specialization, I thought…

Answer (score 5):

```
template <>
struct SomeClass<Foo1>:
  SomeClass<Foo1,Foo2>
{};
```

This will deal with 90% of the kind of problems you describe.  If you need `SomeClass<Foo1>` to be the same as, and not inherited from, `SomeClass<Foo1,Foo2>` you have to write a bunch of aliases and `::type` noise.

```
template<class...Args>
struct Real;

template<class...Args>
struct Helper {
  using type=Real<Args...>;
};

template<class...Args>
using Fake = typename Helper<Args...>::type;
```

this 3 layers is the noise.

`Helper` lets you redefine what arguments mean.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Real<T,U> {
  Real() {
    T t;
    U u;
  }
};

template<>
struct Helper<Foo1>:Helper<Foo1, Foo2> {};
```

we get the `::type` from `Helper<Foo1, Foo2>` here.  `Fake` doesn't see the intermediate `Helper<Foo1>`, so the type we get from `Fake<Foo1>` is `Real<Foo1, Foo2>`, not a derived class.

This ensures that `std::is_same< Fake<Foo1>, Fake<Foo1, Foo2> >`.

`Fake` is the alias template "API" that users use.  `Helper` lets you do some specialization to pick which `Real` template you instantiate based on the arguments passed in.

Comment: Thanks.  In case you have an example that uses a bunch of aliases and `::type` noise I would still be interested for learning purposes =)

Comment: @plg noise added.

Comment: @Adam Outstanding thank you. Took me a while to wrap my head around it.  I think this is not an inelegant solution at all if you do this kind of template parameter inference a lot.  In the program I'm working on now I definitely do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want avoid a inheriting solution proposed by Yakk, you can try with a second template parameter with a default type that depends from the first argument

I mean something as

```
template <typename T, typename U = typename DepDef<T>::type>
struct SomeClass
```

where `DepDef` is a declared template struct

```
template <typename>
struct DepDef;
```

and the default for `Foo1` is defined, through template specialization, as follows

```
template <>
struct DepDef<Foo1>
 { using type = Foo2; };
```

If you want, by example, that the default type for `Foo3` is `Foo4`, you can add the following specialization

```
template <>
struct DepDef<Foo3>
 { using type = Foo4; };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo1 { Foo1() { std::cout << "Foo1 "; } };
struct Foo2 { Foo2() { std::cout << "Foo2 "; } };
struct Foo3 { Foo3() { std::cout << "Foo3 "; } };
struct Foo4 { Foo4() { std::cout << "Foo4 "; } };

template <typename> struct DepDef;

template <> struct DepDef<Foo1> { using type = Foo2; };
template <> struct DepDef<Foo3> { using type = Foo4; };

template <typename T, typename U = typename DepDef<T>::type>
struct SomeClass
 { T t; U u; };

int main ()
 {
   SomeClass<Foo1, Foo2>  f0;
   SomeClass<Foo1, Foo3>  f1;
   SomeClass<Foo1>        f2; // default Foo2
   SomeClass<Foo3, Foo4>  f3;
   SomeClass<Foo3, Foo1>  f4;
   SomeClass<Foo3>        f5; // default Foo4
   SomeClass<Foo2, Foo1>  f6;  
   //SomeClass<Foo2>        f7; // compilation error: no default defined for Foo2
 }
```

Observe that the `f7` definition (the last one) fails because isn't defined a `DepDef` specialization for `Foo2`.

If you want that there is a generic default (a default when a `DefDep` specialization isn't defined), you can define it inside the declaration

```
template <typename>
struct DepDef
 { type = void; }; // generic default
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out later today